# "Too much recursion" when using recursive function from within a namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, javascript-namespaces

I'm using a recursive method in javascript which worked perfectly fine, until I put it in a namespace. The function returns an element which has the given quoteproduct id as it's id attribute from an array. It's a nested array, that's why the function is recursive. This is the function declaration :

```
QuoteProductService.getQuoteProduct = function (quoteproductid) {
    var founditem = null;
    $.each(QuoteProductService.QuoteProductConfigurations, function (index, item) {
        if(item.id == quoteproductid) {
            founditem = item;
            return false; // break the $.each if an item is found
        } else {
            founditem = QuoteProductService.getQuoteProduct(item.children, quoteproductid);
            if(founditem != null) return false; // break the $.each if an item is found
        }
    });
    return founditem;
}
```

This is how I'm declaring the namespace :

```
var QuoteProductService = QuoteProductService || {};
```

and this is the array in the namespace that I'm using in the function :

```
QuoteProductService.QuoteProductConfigurations = [];
```

This array is populated when the page loads.

Now, whenever I call the function, I get a "too much recursion" error. What am I doing wrong ? Again, this function worked before I put the function and array in a namespace.

Comment: `QuoteProductService.getQuoteProduct` only takes 1 parameter, but in your `else`, you're passing it 2.  So, it's now searching for `item.id == item.children` which may always be false, which will keep running your function.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I'm sorry for overlooking this. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: No problem.  Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just rewritten your code with simpler variable names:

```
var a = {
    b: = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
};
a.get = function( searchId ) {
    var match = null;

    $.each(a.b, function(key, value) {
        if ( value.id === searchId ) {
            // Yes we found the match, break and everything

            match = value;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            match = a.get();

            if ( match ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return match;
};
```

---

```
a.get(1) // will return {id: 1}
a.get(2) // will throw recursive error
```

Why?

Because of your structure, As you always points the `$.each` to `a.b`.

And therefore it goes something like this:

> Loop over `a.b`: 
>   a.b[0].id === searchId ?
>   Ok everything is good return first value
>
> if not a.b[0].id === searchId
>   Loop over `a.b`
>   a.b[0].id === searchId ?
>   Ok everything is good return first value
>   if not a.b[0].id === searchId
>   Loop over `a.b`
>   .....

Hope you understand:

To fix this you will need to specify what array that it is we have to loop over:

```
QuoteProductService.getQuoteProduct = function (quoteproductid, loopArray) {
    var founditem = null;

    // if (loopArray) {loopArray = loopArray} else { loopArray=Quote...QuteConfig.. }
    loopArray = loopArray || QuoteProductService.QuoteProductConfigurations;

    $.each(loopArray, function (index, item) {
        if(item.id == quoteproductid) {
            founditem = item;
            return false; // break the $.each if an item is found
        } else {
            founditem = QuoteProductService.getQuoteProduct(quoteproductid, item.children);
            if(founditem != null) return false; // break the $.each if an item is found
        }
    });
    return founditem;
}
```